# Error with design appearance

Tags: android

I have the following error with my android studio and it appeared when I tried to select a tablet instead of phone to see the design compatibility. It refuses to show the design anymore. Even when I tried to create new project it refuses to show the design.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:89)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:68)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:277)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:161)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Some tips since this is your first question: rather than posting only a stack trace, please also specify what your question is.  Also, if your goal is to make the error go away, please also specify what solutions you've already attempted, and what the result was.  Finally, since viewers of this question aren't likely to be familiar with your codebase, please specify the most recent line from the stack trace which relates to code that you've written (as opposed to code from a library/framework).

Comment: @RichieThomas Unfortunately, switching the display from phone to table is probably all there is.  The error appears to be coming from Android Studio's internal preview code and not the project; I'm getting the same thing on a just-created project I've yet to edit at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to edit your **style AppTheme**. Because AppTheme in lastest appcompat librabry 28 get theme from Base.

**FIX**
Goto Values > styles.xml and modify the style as follows,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

or you can use a different base theme you like.

Comment: Many thanks Simran, it works fine now, your support is highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to downgrade to 27. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308918/7429464

Answer (score 3):

On a hunch I went digging into the build files for anything involving version numbers, since [the docs say](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener) `OnUnhandledKeyEventListener` method was only added in sdk version 28.  After making these changes to `app/build.gradle` (to use a non-alpha sdk version), the errors stopped and the layout editor preview started working:

```
--- a/App/app/build.gradle
+++ b/App/app/build.gradle
@@ -1,11 +1,11 @@
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
-    compileSdkVersion 28
+    compileSdkVersion 25
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.paklena.helloworld"
         minSdkVersion 15
-        targetSdkVersion 28
+        targetSdkVersion 25
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@ android {

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
-    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
+    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```