# Android studio preview does not show layouts

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just started to learn android studio. I've encountered a problem:

[image]

The layouts won't appear in the preview after I have added them. But if I change the theme or run the app in the emulator they do appear but they overlap.

Comment: What a render problem? Show me the gradle file, pls!

Comment: it display "Failed to load Apcompat actionBar with unknown error"

Comment: Use an correct api level to work with your layout components. Maybe changing to 26 or bellow and adjusting the dependencies it will work fine. Try it, pls!

Comment: i can't change the api level ..the only level available is 28 :/

Comment: Bro, unfortunally the problem occur for this cause. I was solve the issue using 26 or bellow. Using 28 and dependencies pointing to 28.0.0-alpha3 my `CoordinatorLayout` not was working fine

Comment: @AbnerEscócio please use the solution in my answer for API 28

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For API 27:**

Add the following dependency:
If you are using targetSdkVersion 27,
in your App Level gradle file **build.gradle(Module: app)**

**implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'**

**For API 28:**

if you are using targetSdkVersion 28,

**Step 1:**
Make sure you have the following dependency:

**implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'**

**UPDATE:** For the latest appcompat-v7 library repo version, follow this link

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google

**Step 2:**

Goto Values > styles.xml and modify the style as follows,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

or any other base theme you like.

Here is an example constraint layout for you,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enter_age"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter age"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:onClick="butGetAge"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/enter_age"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: i'm sorry for this question xD . but i'm new to android studio, what do you mean by: In your App Level gradle file build.gradle(Module: app)

Add the following dependency: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: Update : i have checked the gradle file and there is already a implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

Comment: @ErrahbiZouhair please use api 27 for your build.gradle .  Change compileSdkVersion 27, targetSdkVersion 27 and use 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: @ErrahbiZouhair please check the updated answer. If you want to use targetSdkVersion 28 then go to values > styles.xml and modify the parent as,  parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: yes I had the same problem. `parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` solved it.

Comment: Yes ..the last solution was it !! Thank you so much!