# How can i fix Android Studio Render Problem?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have tried to do a fresh windows installation clean hard drive partition and then update windows to latest version install all driver and download and install android studio latest version completely then check for android studio updates but when i create a new android studio project then i go to `activity.xml` file then i saw white layout in editor and an error says

> Render problem
>   Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

and another error says

> Failed to instantiate one or more classes 
>   The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Copy stack to clipboard

i have tried everything but only one thing was working before update is to change 
    implementation `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02`
to `alpha` or `beta` but now its not working.Is there any other way to solve this problem permanently.
please help

Comment: Go to Build->Clean Project OR invalid cache and restart
if above solution not work you need to change support dependency from  build.gradle file. use stable design support library.

Comment: change your default theme to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: Clean and rebuild helps if not Can you show Gradle file?

Comment: Thank you so much my problem got solved by changing theme to <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> Thank you but is there anyway to fix this problem permanently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android/view/view$onUnhandledKeyEventListener (onMeasure error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305964/android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener-onmeasure-error)

Comment: Please refer to step 2 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307987/android-studio-preview-does-not-show-layouts/51308918